# How to combine strings without a final delimiter

Tags: python, printing

This is my code:

My input: kjishdui@

Expected output = "Digit missing, Uppercase missing"

Current output = "Digit missing, Uppercase missing,"

```
s=input("Create new password: ")
digit=0
upper=0
lower=0
special=0
for i in s:
    if (ord(i) >=48 and ord(i)<=57):
        digit+=1
    if (ord(i) >= 65 and ord(i)<=90):
        upper+=1
    if (ord(i) >= 97 and ord(i) <= 122):
        lower+=1
    if (ord(i)==95 or ord(i)==64 or ord(i)==35 or ord(i)==36):
        special+=1

d='Digit missing'
u='Uppercase missing'
l='Lowercase missing'
s='Special character missing'
if digit==0:
    print(d, end=',')
if upper==0:
    print(u, end=',')
if lower==0:
    print (l, end=',')
if special==0:
    print (s)
if digit>0 and upper>0 and lower>0 and specialcase>0:
    print("Password granted")
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to put them all in a list, then join them and print them all out at once (if there are any):

```
d='Digit missing'
u='Uppercase missing'
l='Lowercase missing'
s='Special character missing'

error_list = []
if digit==0:
    error_list.append(d)
if upper==0:
    error_list.append(u)
if lower==0:
    error_list.append(l)
if special==0:
    error_list.append(s)
if len(error_list) > 0:
    print(", ".join(error_list))
else:
    print("Password granted")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the 1st part of your code could be done this way - no need to matter of unicode characters code.

```
s = input("Create new password: ")
digit = 0
upper = 0
lower = 0
special = 0
for i in s:
    if s.isdigit():
        digit += 1
    elif s.isupper():
        upper += 1
    elif s.islower():
        lower += 1
    elif not s.isalnum(): # or just else
        special += 1
```

or maybe even better:

```
s = input("Create new password: ")
digit = sum(c.isdigit() for c in s)
upper = sum(c.isupper() for c in s)
lower  = sum(c.islower() for c in s)
special  = sum(not c.isalnum() and not c.isspace() for c in s) # whitespaces are not special characters
```

And the second part can be done with list comprehension, by adding to list of messages (errors) only those messaged which corresponing vlaues are 0

```
d = 'Digit missing'
u = 'Uppercase missing'
l = 'Lowercase missing'
s = 'Special character missing'
errors = [err for err, val in [(d, digit), (u, upper), (l, lower), (s, special)] if val == 0]
if errors:
    print(", ".join(errors))
else:
    print("Password generated")
```

To make it even more beautiful we can create list of tuples with message - count_value:

```
message_value_list = [
    ('Digit missing', digit), 
    ('Uppercase missing', upper), 
    ('Lowercase missing', lower), 
    ('Special character missing', special)
]
```

and use it in list comprehension.
Or to be super  brief it can be done like that:

```
s = input("Create new password: ")
print(
    ", ".join([err for err, count in [
        ('Digit missing', sum(c.isdigit() for c in s)), 
        ('Uppercase missing', sum(c.isupper() for c in s)), 
        ('Lowercase missing', sum(c.islower() for c in s)), 
        ('Special character missing', sum(not c.isalnum() and not c.isspace() for c in s))
    ] if count == 0
        ] 
    ) or "Password generated"
)
```